# Retrieve results between two patterns plus one line in sed

Tags: sed

I would like to extract all lines between `INFO:root:id is` and one line after the `INFO:root:newId`.

Can anyone advise how I can achieve this?

Currently I'm using

```
sed -n '/INFO:root:id is/,/INFO:root:newId/p' 1/python.log
```

and I'm  trying to figure out how to print one line after the second pattern match.

```
INFO:root:id is
INFO:root:16836211
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): abc.hh.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://abc.hh.com:443 "POST /api/v2/import/row.json HTTP/1.1" 201 4310
INFO:root:newId
INFO:root:35047536
INFO:root:id is
INFO:root:46836211
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): abc.hh.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://abc.hh.com:443 "POST /api/v2/import/row.json HTTP/1.1" 201 4310
INFO:root:newId
INFO:root:55547536
```

Comment: Can you show us your expected output ? You have two sets between `INFO:root:id is` and `INFO:root:newId`, do you want only the first set or both ?

Comment: what i want to achieve is to extract the original id and the new id. i wanted to retrieve all records that matches the mentioned pattern because i wanted to filter out some of the records may not have a newID due to an error.

Comment: Couldn't you just grep all the lines starting with `INFO:root:` and followed by `id is`, `newId` or a bunch of digits? `grep -E 'INFO:root:(id is|newId|[[:digit:]]+)' infile` would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding question correctly

```
$ seq 10 | sed -n '/3/,/5/{/5/N;p;}'
3
4
5
6
```

- `/3/` is starting regex and `/5/` is ending regex
- `/5/N` get additional line for ending regex
- tested on `GNU sed`, syntax might differ for other versions

With `awk`

```
$ seq 10 | awk '/3/{f=1} f; /5/{f=0; if((getline a)>0) print a}'
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: any easy way to print something like

old id, new id

Comment: There's no reason to use `getline` for this. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for the issues around using it and when it IS appropriate to use it (i.e. not here!).  @pothios sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines **that is all** - post a new question with the sample input and expected output you **really** want (e.g. ids) to get help solving your problem with an appropriate tool, eg. awk

Answer (score 0):

Unclear whether you want only the first set of lines after a match or all matches.

If you want the first set between the matching patterns, it is easy if you use `/INFO:root:id/` for your end match as well and then use `head -n -1` to print everything but the last line.

```
$ sed -n '/INFO:root:id is/,/INFO:root:id/p' test.txt  | head -n -1
INFO:root:id is
INFO:root:16836211
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): abc.hh.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://abc.hh.com:443 "POST /api/v2/import/row.json HTTP/1.1" 201 4310
INFO:root:newId
INFO:root:35047536
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use flags to indicate when you've found the beginning and ending regexps and print accordingly:

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'e{print buf $0; buf=""; b=e=0} /3/{b=1} b{buf = buf $0 ORS; if (/5/) e=1}'
3
4
5
6
```

Note that this does not have the potential issue of printing lines when there's only the beginning or ending regexp present but not both. The other answers, including your currently accepted answer, have that problem:

```
$ seq 10 | sed -n '/3/,/27/{/27/N;p;}'
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ seq 10 | awk '/3/{f=1} f; /27/{f=0; if((getline a)>0) print a}'
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ seq 10 | awk 'e{print buf $0; buf=""; b=e=0} /3/{b=1} b{buf = buf $0 ORS; if (/27/) e=1}'
$
```

Note that the script I posted correctly didn't print anything because a block of text beginning with 3 and ending with 27 was not present in the input.